# Custom setting checbox always giving false in production

Tags: customsetting

I have trigger on which i am trying to control on\off through customsetting.

I have using
`Boolean toRunTrigger = Trigger_Run_Logic__c.getInstance().RunClassObjectTrigger__c`*

This was givning right behaviour in lower sandboxes but in production this is always giving false.

Please explain.

Thanks
Arun Sharma

Comment: Visibility i have put protected,but it was working fine in lower sandboxes.It is not giving option to change the visibility from protected to public

Comment: Did you set org defaults in production?

Comment: go to your custom setting and click on manage button there you can see the value of each field check if its true or false there. thank you.